# Full calendar not ordering the events in correct order

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I am using [Full Calendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) plugin. I want the events ordering to be according to the start date/time ascending. As you can see below `event # 2`, `event # 3` & `event # 4` are in the correct order but `event # 1` is not in the correct order. It should be in the last.

Wrong Order:

```
[
    {"id":"1","title":"AAA","start":"2013-04-01 00:00:00","end":"2013-04-01 23:59:59", "allDay":false},
    {"id":"2","title":"BBB","start":"2013-04-01 07:30:00","end":"2013-04-01 09:30:00", "allDay":false},
    {"id":"3","title":"CCC","start":"2013-04-01 08:00:00","end":"2013-04-01 10:30:00", "allDay":false},
    {"id":"4","title":"DDD","start":"2013-04-01 13:00:00","end":"2013-04-01 10:30:00", "allDay":false},
]
```

How i wanted it to be (Order By Time ASC):

```
[
    {"id":"2","title":"BBB","start":"2013-04-01 07:30:00","end":"2013-04-01 09:30:00", "allDay":false},
    {"id":"3","title":"CCC","start":"2013-04-01 08:00:00","end":"2013-04-01 10:30:00", "allDay":false},
    {"id":"4","title":"DDD","start":"2013-04-01 13:00:00","end":"2013-04-01 10:30:00", "allDay":false},
    {"id":"1","title":"AAA","start":"2013-04-01 23:00:00","end":"2013-04-01 23:59:59", "allDay":false}
]
```

It looks perfect in the `Week View` & `Day View` but not ordering perfectly in the `Month View`. All the events are coming from the database and i am passing JSON feed to the `fullcalendar` to render the events. Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use underscore.js to sort the object array.

```
var events = [
    {"id":"1","title":"AAA","start":"2013-04-01 23:00:00","end":"2013-04-01 23:59:59", "allDay":false},
    {"id":"2","title":"BBB","start":"2013-04-01 07:30:00","end":"2013-04-01 09:30:00", "allDay":false},
    {"id":"3","title":"CCC","start":"2013-04-01 08:00:00","end":"2013-04-01 10:30:00", "allDay":false},
    {"id":"4","title":"DDD","start":"2013-04-01 13:00:00","end":"2013-04-01 10:30:00", "allDay":false}
];



var sortedEvents = _.sortBy(events, function(data){ return data.start; });
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/maheshsapkal/cG3Sg/)**